# How to structure a class so that it can be used to deserialize a JSON string that has nested elements

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am working with an API that returns a JSON response as follows;

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

{
  "SAPISetPermitInfo_response" : {
    "RC" : "value",
    "MessageText" : "value"
  }
}
```

And I want to create a c# class definition that I can use with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SAPISetPermitInfoResponse>(response);
```

But I am not sure how to structure the SAPISetPermitInfoResponse class so that it works correctly with the response JSON string, due to the nested elements.

Currently, we are using a helper method to essentially strip the "SAPISetPermitInfo_response" element form the JSON string and then deserializing the result, like this...

```
IDictionary<string, JToken> foo = JObject.Parse(response);
string key = foo.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.EndsWith("_response"));
response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo[key]);
```

However, it seems like there should be a way to create the SAPISetPermitInfoResponse class so that it allows for the nested elements without needing the helper method to parse the JSON string. But, so far, I have not had any luck finding one.

I have seen a post where they suggested creating two classes, one that just has a dictionary property of type , where the object is another class that has the RC and MessageText properties, but that seems a bit cumbersome and should require two classes for each different API method response. (This API has about 90 different methods that all return a JSON response that starts with the method name followed by "_response" in a similar nested manner).

I have no control over the API's response string so I have to work with what I have been given. I just want to make sure I am doing it the correct and most efficient way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Result
{
    public SAPISetPermitInfo SAPISetPermitInfo_response { get; set; }
}

public class SAPISetPermitInfo
{
    public string RC { get; set; }

    public string MessageText { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
string json = ... the JSON shown in your question
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
Console.WriteLine(response.SAPISetPermitInfo_response.RC);
Console.WriteLine(response.SAPISetPermitInfo_response.MessageText);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create the following class:

```
public class SAPISetPermitInfoResponse
{
    public string RC { get; set; }
    public string MessageText { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public SAPISetPermitInfoResponse SAPISetPermitInfo_response { get; set; }
}
```

And when you want to parse the required Json you need to be able to get only the Json from the API response without the Headers, lets say we have

```
string responseJson = "{ \"SAPISetPermitInfo_response\" : {\"RC\" : \"value\",\"MessageText\" : \"value\"}}";
```

we can send it to the following function to get the object from the Json string:

```
    public RootObject GetObjectFromResponse(string responseJson)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseJson);
    }
```

Also just for knowledge you can use the following site to create any given Json to class object:

http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Given that the API has about 90 methods and each one returns a result that has the name of the method followed by "_response", doesn't this solution mean that I would need to create two classes for each method (one each for the method properties and one each for each different method root. Or will this still deserialize through JsonConvert if my RootObject class has properties for each different method (so 1 RootObject class with 90 properties) even though my response string will only reference one of the properties?

Comment: @EiEiGuy It seems like you can use *JsonConverter* abstract class to avoid writing 90 proerties, but hard to say more without more samples...

Comment: yes, given this API you will have to create one RootObject with 90 different properties if all 90 has the same class reference for their response and only those that has data will be converted.